# Highlighting the Menu Item for the Current Page Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, navigation, highlight

I want to highlight the menu items for the current page with a triangle and i used this code

```
.current-menu-ancestor > a,
.current-menu-item > a,
.current-page-ancestor > a,
.current_page_item > a{
background-image:url(‘http://www.dailybodycare.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/triunghi_rosu_meniu.svg’);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center bottom;
}
```

but when i select a sub menu item, that item is highlight and i dont want that. when i click on a sub menu item i just want to highlight the ancestor or parent without the sub menu item.

I know i should use this code

```
.main-navigation li.current_page_parent > a {
background-image:url(‘http://www.dailybodycare.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/triunghi_rosu_meniu.svg’);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center bottom;
}
```

or this one

```
.main-navigation li.current-page-ancestor > a {
background-image:url(‘http://www.dailybodycare.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/triunghi_rosu_meniu.svg’);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center bottom;
}
```

I think they do the same think but im not sure how to write the code correct.

here is my website address www dot dailybodycare dot dk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ul.menunav-menu >` to the start of your selector, that way it'll only target the top level links.

For example, update your current selector to this:

```
ul.menunav-menu > .current-menu-ancestor > a, 
ul.menunav-menu > .current-menu-item > a, 
ul.menunav-menu > .current-page-ancestor > a, 
ul.menunav-menu > .current_page_item > a {
    background-image: url('http://www.dailybodycare.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/triunghi_rosu_meniu.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help....that was exactly what i wanted to do, if it's not to much can you show me how to change the triangle image(.svg) with a css  triangle<br/> `.curent{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 position: center;
 content:"";
 display:block;
 border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: 60px;}
}`     `.curent` its the class of all menu links. thank you again for the help.

Comment: replace that answer above with this: ul.menunav-menu > .current-menu-ancestor > a, 
ul.menunav-menu > .current-menu-item > a, ul.menunav-menu > .current-page-ancestor > a, ul.menunav-menu > .current_page_item > a { position:relative; }

Comment: then remove the css you used for ".curent" and add this:
ul.menunav-menu > .current-menu-ancestor > a:after, 
ul.menunav-menu > .current-menu-item > a:after, 
ul.menunav-menu > .current-page-ancestor > a:after, 
ul.menunav-menu > .current_page_item > a:after { width: 0; height: 0; position: absolute; content:""; display:block; border-left: 8px solid transparent; border-right: 8px solid transparent; border-bottom: 8px solid #000; left: 50%; bottom:0; margin-left:-8px; }

Comment: thx, works but the triangle its not centered in the middle of the text because i have `padding: 0 0 0 25px;` , shoud i increase `left: 50%` to 55% or 60%?

Comment: No, adjust the margin-left value instead

Comment: thank you a lot... if you have time and if i dont ask to much can you help me with this to. i want the menu items that has a sub menu to have an ▼, to indacate that there is a sub menu but on hover and as a curent page i want the ▼ to be hidden. thank you again  `.menunav-menu ul < li a:hover:before {
    content:  "▼";
    float:right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top:auto;
    font-size:10px;
vertical-align: middle;
}`

Comment: Somehting like this:
ul.menunav-menu > .menu-item-has-children:after {content:"▼";top:40px;position:absolute;}
ul.menunav-menu > .menu-item-has-children:hover:after,
ul.menunav-menu > .current_page_item > a:after {content:""}